# Tying a stream to itself

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream

Why does this code run successfully on g++ and clang ([libstdc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c88801b6890fe14)) but give a segmentation fault with [libc++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6a7d1acc1560bc0c):

```c++
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout.tie(&std::cout);
    std::cout << 123;
}
```

What I think should happen is that `std::cout.flush()` should be called before the output actually occurs. Why would this give a segmentation fault?

Comment: Why do you think that? Where did you read that tieing a stream to itself is valid? Explaining the premise of your question would help to tailor an answer.

Comment: If you do stupid things expect stupid results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[ostream.unformatted]/p7:

> ```
> basic_ostream& flush();
> ```
>
> 7 Effects: Behaves as an unformatted output function [...]

[ostream.unformatted]/p1:

> Each unformatted output function begins execution by constructing an
>   object of class `sentry`.

[ostream::sentry]/p2:

> ```
> explicit sentry(basic_ostream<charT,traits>& os);
> ```
>
> 2 If `os.good()` is nonzero, prepares for formatted or unformatted
>   output. If `os.tie()` is not a null pointer, calls
>   `os.tie()->flush()`.<sup>324</sup>
>
> 3 [...]
>
> <sup>324</sup> The call `os.tie()->flush()` does not necessarily occur
>   if the function can determine that no synchronization is necessary.

If you tie a stream to itself, then to flush the stream, it constructs a `sentry`, which tries to flush the stream, which constructs a `sentry`, which  tries to flush the stream, which constructs a `sentry`, which tries to flush the stream, which constructs a `sentry`......I think you see where this is going.

If you get (un)lucky, the implementation might skip the `flush()` call somewhere per footnote 324; otherwise, you'll see the title of this site.

Comment: It's not going _anywhere_!